I can't seem to properly update this array structure in nextjs
I have an array structure that is proving difficult to be updated the right way. The current function that I have updates all array index at once which is not what I want. I want to update the targeted index. These are my codes here:
 const [readMoreState, setReadMoreState] = useState<readMoreStateAttributes[]>([]);

//this helps to create a copy replica of the question data structure to enable readmore to work across all question types

useEffect(()=>{
    
    const tempReadMoreArray: readMoreStateAttributes[] = [];

    let tempReadMoreData:readMoreStateAttributes  = {
        textReadMore: [] as {questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}[],
        plainReadMore: [] as {questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}[],
        checkBoxReadMore:[] as {questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}[],
        multipleReadMore:[] as {questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}[],
        fileReadMore:[] as {questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}[],
        dateReadMore:[] as {questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}[]
    }
   
    temporaryPackageData?.forEach((packageList, packageIndex)=>{
        
           tempReadMoreData.plainReadMore = new Array<{questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}>(packageList?.questions?.length).fill({questionType: 'Plain', selectedIndex: null});
           tempReadMoreData.textReadMore = new Array<{questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}>(packageList?.questions?.length).fill({questionType: 'Text', selectedIndex: null});
           tempReadMoreData.checkBoxReadMore = new Array<{questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}>(packageList?.questions?.length).fill({questionType: 'Checkbox', selectedIndex: null});
           tempReadMoreData.dateReadMore = new Array<{questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}>(packageList?.questions?.length).fill({questionType: 'Date', selectedIndex: null});
           tempReadMoreData.fileReadMore = new Array<{questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}>(packageList?.questions?.length).fill({questionType: 'File', selectedIndex: null});
           tempReadMoreData.multipleReadMore = new Array<{questionType: questionTypeAttributes, selectedIndex: number | null}>(packageList?.questions?.length).fill({questionType: 'Multiple choice', selectedIndex: null});

           tempReadMoreArray?.push(tempReadMoreData)
    })
    setReadMoreState(tempReadMoreArray as readMoreStateAttributes[]);
}, [temporaryPackageData?.length])

This function tries to target the index and update the object array's targeted index.
const handleReadMoreFunc = (params: {questionEvent: 
          questionTypeAttributes, packageIndex: number, 
       questionIndex: null | number, readMoreAction: 'Read More' | 'Read Less', targetIndex?: number, })=>{
   const {questionEvent, packageIndex, questionIndex, readMoreAction, targetIndex} = params;
 let result:readMoreStateAttributes[]  = [...readMoreState];

  readMoreState?.map((item, index)=>{
if(index === packageIndex){
 
  if(questionEvent === 'Text'){
     if(readMoreAction === 'Read More'){
   result[packageIndex].textReadMore[questionIndex as number] = {
...result[packageIndex].textReadMore[questionIndex as number],   questionType: 'Text', selectedIndex: questionIndex}
     } else if(readMoreAction === 'Read Less'){
 result[packageIndex].textReadMore[questionIndex as number] = {
 ...result[packageIndex].textReadMore[questionIndex as number], questionType: 'Text', selectedIndex: null
                    } 
                    }  
   }

}
});

setReadMoreState(result)
}

What I expected to happen is that update the array based on the packageIndex that comes with the function. If the index is 0, simply update the first object in the array and leave the others the way they are.
The attached image shows the result of the function when clicked. 
The first object contains the values parameter sent via the onclick event which contains values such as the targeted package index, the targeted question index, the question event type, etc.
From that action, I am expecting the function to update the first package in the array and the first question in the textReadMore array. It however updated the both package index. That is index 0 and index 1. How do I fix this?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Also, it would be helpful if you could improve the indentation of the code so that it is readable.
